# Multiselect not working when array is initialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using primeng Multiselect, I have written some logic to push data based on search value from backend, for pushing element we have to initialize it first, other it gives me an error of push of undefined, but when I am using by initializing dropdown's array variable, it doesn't showing me the data which I got from API.

On the other hand when I am not initializing the dropdown data variable, and directly assigning data which I got from API then it is working,

I am attaching the stackblitz link where I am facing issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-qykbzn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

> this is working code when I am not initializing it

```
dropdownData;

    getCountryData(countryName: string) {
        const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name';
        this.http
            .get(`${url}/${countryName}?fullText=true`)
            .pipe(debounceTime(20000))
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.dropdownData = data.map((item) => ({
                    ...item,
                    countryName: item.name.common,
                    code: item.fifa
                }));

                // if (localDropdownData.length) {
                //  localDropdownData.forEach((element) => {
                //      this.dropdownData.push(element);
                //  });
                // }
                console.log('data', this.dropdownData);
                this.cd.detectChanges();
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change the value assignment from

```
   localDropdownData.forEach((element) => {
     this.dropdownData.push(element);
   });
```

to

```
   this.dropdownData=[...localDropdownData];
```

`array.push` does not change the variable reference, hence it is not picked up by angular change detection.

Comment: but it is not satisfying my use case, I have to push every element of localDropdownData in this.dropdownData

Comment: if you want change detection to work then you have to create a new array everytime when you push like this    `this.dropdownData=[...this.dropdownData, element];`

Comment: tried it, but not working

Comment: i tried you stackbliz but the api call isn't working, if you can make it work i can help you debug

Comment: api accepting the full name of country, if you put india, you will get the result